# Why is mercury magnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, metals

Why is this mercury magnetic and spin when an electric current is applied?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSIzyk5Mjko

Where is the stator? Where is the rotor? What is the path the electricity takes?

Comment: Please include enough information in your question so that one can reconstruct what it is asking even if the link  no longer works - currently I have no idea what this question is asking unless I follow the link and watch a video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mercury is not and does not become "magnetic". I mean it does not change its material magnetic properties becoming ferromagnetic, like iron.
What you see there is the interaction between an electric current and a magnetic field. The current goes through the mercury and the magnetic field exerts a force on the current carrying conductor.   As I understand the setup, the current "flows" in a radial direction (from center to edge or vice-versa) and the field of the permanent magnet has a vertical component. So the Lorentz force has a tangential component. There are several versions of "motors" based on the fact that mercury is a liquid conductor.
If you want to stick labels, the magnet is the stator and the mercury is the rotor (it's rotating, isn't it?).

Comment: So the magnetic field of the magnet works on the cross section of mercury that lies between two electrodes, and is pushing the electrons from the electric current, which happen to be mobile, which then pushes the mercury at that cross section, and repeats every time new mercury crosses that line?

Comment: One electrode is the bolt in the middle. The other is the hemispheric bowl. It is in the videos's description. I don't know what you mean by "the magnet works on the cross section".  The magnet produces magnetic field. The magnetic filed produces a force on electric currents if the currents are not completely along the direction of the field.