# Does mercury spin when heated by a flame?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I heard that if a dish of mercury is heated by a moving flame placed under it, the mercury will spin around -

> Sanderson [Ivan T. Sanderson, biologist and paranormal researcher] then goes on to make the basic observation that a circular dish of mercury revolves in a contrary manner to a naked flame circulated below it, and that it gathers speed until it exceeds the speed of revolution of said flame.

Now, as in this question [Why is mercury magnetic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331772/why-is-mercury-magnetic) , if an electric current is passed through the mercury in the presence of a magnetic field, the mercury will spin around, but I can't find any reference to a version with a flame.  Is this true/would this theoretically be true?  If so, why?  Or was the person who said this just misremembering the electric current version?

Comment: Where did you hear this from? Could it be convection effects? Because from a symmetry argument it doesn’t seem likely that the mercury should spin in any direction if just heated from below.

Comment: you are probably correct it is a mistaken impression of the person probably from seeing something like in this video in the answer and not remembering the words https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742864/why-does-liquid-mercury-start-spinning-in-a-magnetic-field/742947#742947  it looks like a frying pan :) .

Comment: Apparently, it's from a fringe book about vimanas, quoting something I can't find by Ivan T. Sanderson https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=XyvtdDEc1PwC&q=Sanderson&f=false#v=snippet&q=Sanderson&f=false , so going by the usual standards of research of fringe books it's entirely possible that it's a mistake - as for the symmetry thing, though, on checking it again it turns out that it's referring to a flame that is itself moving in circles, added the quote to the question.

Comment: This paper makes the same claim about a rotating open flame and liquid mercury. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17780176/ I found the complete paper https://www2.whoi.edu/staff/jwhitehead/wp-content/uploads/sites/123/2017/11/1969_Schubert_MovingFlame_Science.pdf